# How to combine columns from join table results?

Tags: mysql, database, select, join

I have a mysql table that looks like this:

Table PaymentType

```
ID   PaymentCode   PaymentName
1      P1        CASH
2      P2        TRANSFER
3      P3        CREDIT CARD
```

Table PERSONS

```
ID   ID_PERSON   PersonName
1      123        GEORGE
2      124        HENRY
3      125        MICHAEL
4      126        ANNA
```

Table INVOICE_IN

```
ID   ID_INVOICE_IN   Person_ID  Amount PaymentType_ID
1      II-001            1       100      1
2      II-002            2       200      1
3      II-003            4       300      2
```

Table INVOICE_OUT

```
ID   ID_INVOICE_OUT   Person_ID  Amount     PaymentType_ID
1      IO-001                 1       500      2
1      IO-002                 3       600      3
```

I want the result like this:

```
ID_INVOICE_IN PaymentCode  PersonName  Amount ID_INVOICE_OUT PaymentCode  PersonName  Amount
II-001            P1         George     100        IO-001     P2          George      500 
II-002            P1         Henry      200        IO-002     P3       Michael       600 
II-003            P2         Anna       300         NULL      NULL       NULL      NULL
```

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT INVOICE_IN.ID_INVOICE_IN, PaymentType.PaymentCode, PERSONS.PersonName, INVOICE_IN.Amount FROM INVOICE_IN LEFT JOIN PaymentType ON PaymentType.id = INVOICE_IN.PaymentType_ID LEFT JOIN PERSONS ON PERSONS.id = INVOICE_IN.Person_ID
```

The query successfully shows 4 columns **for invoice_in**.

and I also have a query like this:

```
SELECT INVOICE_OUT.ID_INVOICE_OUT, PaymentType.PaymentCode, PERSONS.PersonName, INVOICE_OUT.Amount FROM INVOICE_OUT LEFT JOIN PaymentType ON PaymentType.id = INVOICE_OUT.PaymentType_ID LEFT JOIN PERSONS ON PERSONS.id = INVOICE_OUT.Person_ID
```

The query successfully shows 4 columns **for invoice_out**

I need to combine between result1 (invoice_in) and result2 (invoice_out), so the result of query has 8 columns.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, it is actually what MySQL is doing and is good at. What have you done so far?

Comment: as far, i only done like showing only one table, i need to combine two tables like the result. so i mean, join table (invoice_in) combine (invoice_out), the result more columns (like above result), the result not in row

Comment: Your table structure is normalized, and connected with IDs. You only need to do a simple `SELECT` and a few `JOIN` clauses on it to glue the rest of the data, nothing too hard.

Comment: yes, using join syntax but i only success for one table. But how to combine the result of join 1 to result join 2 like the above result.

Comment: Please add the "succeeding" code to your answer, so we can work on it.

Comment: School / University assignment? What Avalanche is telling you is that you should at least show some effort by yourself. We won't do your homework, but we'll help you to understand things / get rid of roadblocks when learning. So please edit the question to show what you tried, and what result you got.

Comment: above is my mysql syntax. the result show 4 columns, i need 8 columns for the result (4 columns from table invoice_in and 4 columns from table invoice_out).

Comment: @Tilman Hausheer, thanks for your advised. i will do it.

Comment: @ed.inside You can edit your question. It is better to include the code there, some people don't read the comments.

Comment: i have already changes or edit my question.. sorry to make all of you confused.

Comment: @jpw, thanks for your attentions. invoice_in and invoice_out is not related to each other. Yes, the amount for Michael is 600 (you can see in table invoice_out) and the amount for George is 500. i just need to know or the query for output the result like above (the final result show 8 columns, combined the query result of invoice_in and invoice_out). in fact, the record each table (invoice_in and invoice_out) is different count and the record count is not same/the row result is not same, if empty will show null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right it seems that what you want to do is to show to unrelated sets of data next to each other.

One way to do this is to number the rows in each set and do a left join with the larger set as the left side. (A better way would be to use a `full outer join` but MySQL does not support that although the same effect can be achieved using left/right joins w/ union). With MySQL you would use user variables to number the rows.

This query gives the result from your example, although I don't really see the point of showing unrelated data side by side. (If it really is unrelated... there's nothing in the question that suggests it is related).

```
select 
  t1.id_invoice_in, t1.paymentcode, t1.personname, t1.amount,
  t2.id_invoice_out, t2.paymentcode, t2.personname, t2.amount  
from (
  select     
    id_invoice_in, paymentcode, personname, amount,
    (@r1 := @r1 + 1) as r1
  from invoice_in 
  join paymenttype pt on pt.id = paymenttype_id 
  join persons p on p.id = person_id
  ,(select @r1 := 0) r
) t1 left join (
  select 
    id_invoice_out, paymentcode, personname, amount,
    (@r2 := @r2 + 1) as r2
  from invoice_out 
  join paymenttype pt on pt.id = paymenttype_id 
  join persons p on p.id = person_id
  ,(select @r2 := 0) r
) t2 on t1.r1 = t2.r2;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a633/5)

Comment: thank you so much. You're very Smart! This query i have never seen/know before. thanks for you help. The problem is SOLVED!

Comment: @ed.inside Happy to help :)

Comment: Your query is works and working fine. But i how to use your query in vb.net? i have tried write your query in vb.net and have error "Fatal error encountered during command execution". i guess maybe the query containts @. how to just execute the query without entering parameter add with value. If must entering the value like this: myCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("r", whatisvalue??).

Comment: @ed.inside I'm afraid I can't answer that as I have never used VB.Net. I would guess that you need to escape the symbols somehow but I don't know, sorry.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT 
    `In`.`ID_INVOICE_IN`, 
    `PayI`.`PaymentCode`, 
    `PersI`.`PersonName`, 
    `In`.`Amount`, 
    `Out`.`ID_INVOICE_OUT`, 
    `PayO`.`PaymentCode`, 
    `PersI`.`PersonName`, 
    `Out`.`Amount` 
FROM
    `INVOICE_IN`  AS `In`,
    `INVOICE_OUT` AS `Out`,
    `PERSONS`     AS `PersI`,
    `PERSONS`     AS `PersO`,
    `PaymentType` AS `PayI`,
    `PaymentType` AS `PayO`
WHERE
    `In`.`ID`              = `Out`.`ID`   AND
    `In`.`Person_ID`       = `PersI`.`ID` AND
    `Out`.`Person_ID`      = `PersO`.`ID` AND
    `In`.`PaymentCode_ID`  = `PayI`.`ID`  AND
    `Out`.`PaymentCode_ID` = `PayO`.`ID`
ORDER BY
    `In`.`ID_INVOICE_IN`
```

Comment: I don't think we should be advocating 20th century join syntax in a 21st century Q&A forum

Comment: @Strawberry: Is it wrong? No. Does it make a difference in execution? No. (In fact many database-machines internal convert the JOIN-Syntax into something that looks like what I've written.) Is it easy to understand? Yes!

Comment: The use of pre-SQL92 joins aside, this answer won't produce the desired output as the solution must use outer joins.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast, i have tried your query, but no result (MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0010 sec)

Comment: anyone who can help me?